# Modify object serialization depending on what class is being serialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-web

So my goal is to return some objects as the response body from a Spring REST controller. The thing is, these two objects point each other, something kind of like this:

```
public class Person {
    private Set<Team> teams;
}

public class Team {
    private Set<Person> members;
}
```

If I return these two objects from a controllers mapping method right away, the generated response will be infinite and will probably crash the browser, because the members set has people, and each person has a set of teams, and so on, and everything gets returned infinitely.

How can I manage, instead of showing the whole list of, say, members, to display just the name of each of the members?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check few answeres in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jackson then you must use jackson provided solution to problem you are mentioning.

1. @JsonManagedReference
2. @JsonBackReference

Also look at this link which might be helpful :
[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue),

Also
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#object-references-identity

Comment: Thanks! The biggest issue here is I did not know how to look it up exactly... Infinite recursion, that was the key! Thanks again